# Классификация глаголов с прямым предикатом. 1-й тип: глагол + инфинитив и 2-й тип: глагол + объект

Tags: грамматика, глаголы, английский-язык, аспектология

Существует ряд глаголов, допускающих следование инфинитива:

> Я хочу/пытаюсь/намереваюсь/планирую/думаю/начинаю делать что-то.

Назовем такие глаголы "глаголы с предикатом действия".

С другой стороны, эти глаголы не допускают следование существительного:

> Я пытаюсь/намереваюсь/планирую/думаю/начинаю стол.

("Хочу стол" — это очевидное сокращение словосочетания "Хочу иметь стол", так что будем считать, что хочу стол в буквальном смысле невозможно.)

Таким образом, все глаголы с прямым предикатом можно поделить на глаголы с предикатом действия и глаголы с предикатом объекта (Я даю/покупаю/ставлю/чищу стол).
Грамматика русского языка в этом смысле оказывается очень строгой: глаголы не допускаются быть в обоих группах сразу. Это как бы намекает на то, что дело не столько в грамматике, сколько в самих типах действия, выражаемых соответствующими глаголами.

1-й вопрос: Известно ли такое деление глаголов или я первооткрыватель?

Аналогично и в английском языке: I want/begin/plan to do something.

2-й вопрос:
Как объяснить, почему предикат у действия — другое действие, во фразах:

> I seem to do wrong. // Я кажусь делать неправильно.

> I look to do wrong. // Я выгляжу делать неправильно.

Как может у действия "выглядеть" быть предикатом другое действие?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116556/discussion-on-question-by-user190920-----).

Answer (score 1):

> 1-й вопрос: Известно ли такое деление глаголов или я первооткрыватель?

Нет, не известно. Потому именно, что противоестественно.

> 2-й вопрос: Как объяснить, почему предикат у действия — другое
> действие, во фразах:

На вопрос невозможно дать ответ, ибо он базируется на ложном постулате. Здесь нет предиката, да и само авторское деление на какие-то группы непонятно и скорее всего — ошибочно. Это если говорить о русском языке, а английский — не для этого ресурса.

При необходимости вопрос дополню содержательной критикой предлагаемого подхода.

(+)
По поводу "предиката". В грамматике русского языка термин "предикат" используется исключительно в рамках исследований общей лингвистики. В собственно русской грамматике ему соответвует понятие "сказуемое". Говорить о каких-то "сказуемых действия" и/или "сказуемых объекта" как-то не приходится, это тарабарщина.
Два случая ближе всего (пусть и не полностью) соответствуют конструкциям с простым глагольным сказуемым и составным сказуемым, которое в свою очередь может быть или составным глагольным сказуемым (СГС) или составным именным сказуемым. Автор же в одну из своих групп, насколько можно понять, относит глаголы, потенциально используемые как вспомогательная часть ССГ и близкие к ним по функционалу (в т. ч. фазовые). Во вторую группу, видимо, попадают все остальные переходные глаголы.
Помимо всего прочего, такой подход заставляет думать, что автор путает части речи с членами предложения. Ибо классификация **глаголов** ведется в терминах, традиционно используемых для обсуждения синтаксиса.

(++)

> Таким образом, все глаголы с прямым предикатом

Что такое "прямой предикат"?

> Таким образом, все глаголы с прямым предикатом можно поделить на
> глаголы с предикатом действия и глаголы с предикатом объекта

Неверно. И дело даже не в том, что "прямой предикат" тут совершенно непонятная категория. Силлогизм не проходит. Вам надо доказать, что все глаголы, которые не попадают в первую группу, являются глаголами второй. Из  ваших построений это никак не следует.

Comment: Нет никакого ошибочного постулата. Я вроде ясно объяснил что понимаю под предикатом. Это "аргумент" у глагола. Автор ответа все перепутал. Я хотел поговорить о вещах общих для всех языков: глаголы, субъекты действия, объекты это есть во всех языках. Над ними можно построить какую-то мета-грамматику,  общую для всех. Но я согласен что теория сыровата чтобы о ней говорить

Comment: @user190920 *Я вроде ясно объяснил* - очень много слов. Я тоже объяснил, в чем ложность вашего постулата. В том что глаголы делятся на какие-то группы по предложенному принципу. А неудачный термин только подчеркивает эту неразбериху.

Comment: И я добавил в ответ указание на главную. логическую нестыковку.